# When i toggle mobile menu, all site content below header is pushed down. Any ideas how to go about fixing this?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, mobile

Like the title says, on the mobile version of [this site](http://abetterlook.com) the toggle button on the mobile menu forces all content to be pushed down. id like it to just slide over the content without moving everything. It's a wordpress theme, and im fairly familiar with css and html, but i just cant figure this out.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

By positioning the menu absolute, you are taking it out of the page flow.
This is the most important part:

```
.menu{position:absolute;left:42%;width:10%;margin:0 auto;display:none;}
```

If you take the position absolute and the 42% left values out,the other content will be pushed down.
Here is a basic example, I did not make the most beautiful menu there, but it's good for this purpose.
http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/wKYKGL

Comment: adding `z-index` would be nice, too.

Comment: @Ivan
The problem is, z-index does not work for this one, it's more useful when elements are stacked on each other already.